# EF Core transactions - am I doing it right?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

What I know is EF creates transaction for `DbContext.SaveChanges`.
But I need a block of operations including inserts and I need identity results from them to complete my sequence.
So what I do looks like this:

```cs
using var dbTransaction = context.DataBase.BeginTransaction();
try {
    context.Add(myNewEntity);
    context.SaveChanges();
    otherEntity.RefId = myNewEntity.Id;
    context.Update(otherEntity);
    // some other inserts and updates
    context.SaveChanges();
    dbTransaction.Commit();
}
catch {
    dbTransaction.Rollback();
    throw;
}
```

So I call `SaveChanges` on inserts to get identities and not to break relations.
It looks like transactions in transactions. Is it correct? Is it how it should be done? I mean - `Commit` doesn't require `SaveChanges`? I assume it just saves the changes, but I want to be sure.

Comment: It looks OK to me... No, you don't have to do another SaveChanges after the Commit.

Comment: Basically, `SaveChanges` within a transaction is the equivalent to executing an SQL insert, update, delete statement without committing. So whatever your (insert favorite sql developer tool) does with these statements will also happen on `SaveChanges` and whatever the sql developer tool does on `commit` or `rollback` will happen when you call the corresponding transaction methods. For example, a sequence would still increment even if you roll back.

Comment: `// some other inserts and updates`. What that actually is determines if you really need to start a transaction at all. Maybe you can save an entire object graph in one SaveChanges call. Who knows.

Comment: I use transaction because I need a transaction. It IS actually a financial booking transaction. If one account state has changed, the other one must change. And intermediate operations give identities that must match fields in other records. If anything would fail, the system would be a mess and require some serious maintenance. Transactions guarantee no matter what - things will be done properly (meaning completely) or not done at all.

Comment: I believe you. It's just that not everybody is aware of EF being capable of using generated key values for setting foreign keys *while* atomically saving changes. All I see is your question and your code snippet, not your degree of proficiency in EF.

Comment: I know, it's hard to tell what is being done here with minimalistic examples. It's the hardest part of asking proper questions. Well, we're learning all the time, no matter how long we're into it. There's always more. So next time I would probably describe problem a little better. Anyway - I learned what I wanted here. I read MSDN docs on transactions in EF and I was a little confused TBH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will be working properly, but I prefer to do it this way:

```
try {
    context.Add(myNewEntity);
   var result= context.SaveChanges();
    if(result==0){
       dbTransaction.Rollback();
        ... return  error
     }
    otherEntity.RefId = myNewEntity.Id;
    context.Update(otherEntity);
    // some other inserts and updates
    result=context.SaveChanges();
if(result==0){
       dbTransaction.Rollback();
        ... return  error
     }
    dbTransaction.Commit();
}
catch {
    dbTransaction.Rollback();
    throw;
}
```

It is very usefull if for example you update or add or delete several records.
In this case the result will return the number of effected records and instead of result==0 I usually use if result < ...effected records I expect.